# Moshi and Retrofit cannot parse simple JSON

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, moshi

I am trying to parse this JSON:

```
{
"random number1":
   {AT=
      {av=-54.697, ct=320206.0, mn=-92.47, mx=0.495},
      First_UTC=2020-05-17T14:54:38Z
   },
"random number2":
   {AT=
      {av=-54.6437, ct=3204306.0, mn=-92.47, mx=0.495},
      First_UTC=2020-05-17T14:54:43Z
   }
}
```

I have made a simple adapter class for this

```
 @FromJson
 fun fromJson(json: Map<String, Any>): OuterData {
    var count = 0
    var moshi = Moshi.Builder()
               .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
               .build()
    var adapter = moshi.adapter<InnerData>(InnerData().javaClass)

    json.entries.forEach {
            OuterData.innerData[count++] = adapter.fromJson(test)!!
        }
}
```

```
class InnerData() {
   var AT = DataDetail()
   var First_UTC = ""
}
```

It properly iterates over each "random number" entry and the inner objects all look correct but for some reason I always get the `Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at path $.` error.  It looks like the quotes are getting stripped out of the JSON for some reason and that might be causing an issue. If I use my inner data class directly

Comment: Is that your actual json? Because it looks wrong. The string keys should be within quotes like `"AT"` instead of just `AT`. The error is also saying it's malformed json.

Comment: The actual JSON is very long so I cropped out the majority of the fields but that is what it looks like. The actual JSON response has quotes but for some reason moshi or retrofit is stripping them out at some point and I cannot figure out where.

Comment: The error should say at what line it's wrong, for example `at path $.`. I think the rest of the error message after that should point to some field or line

Comment: All I get is "Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at path $."

Comment: Paste the whole json [here](https://jsonlint.com/) and see if it's a valid json.

Comment: The JSON  from a web browser is fine but the JSON I am getting in fromJSON that has the stripped quotes is invalid.

Comment: Why do you need to create an adapter? You can just create the data class that represents your json and give it to the retrofit interface. Also, this seems wrong `var test = "{" + it.value.toString() + "}"` You need to add extra quotes in there for the keys. That's probably the reason.

Comment: @sonnet That was unintended, just to test what the issue with formatting might be. It makes no difference either way since JsonReader just iteraters over all the objects it was ignored.

I need an adapter because "random number1" might be "random number432532" and I have no idea what it could be. Also it includes some things that aren't these InnerData objects but just strings.